# Percentage of First Calculation in R

Tags: r

I have a data.frame of customers broken down by cohort (indicated by first_week). The "Order n" columns have the counts of each cohort that made an nth order.

```
Ordercounts <- data.frame(first_week = c("Week 1", "Week 2", "Week 3"),
                      "Order 1" = c(100,80,150),
                      "Order 2" = c(86,60,75),
                      "Order 3" = c(60,40,50))
```

What I need is a to calculate the % people for each cohort that made an nth order (as a measure of retention). The output I'd like is:

```
Output <- data.frame(first_week = c("1", "2", "3"),
                      "Order 1" = c(1, 1, 1),
                      "Order 2" = c(.86, .75, .5),
                      "Order 3" = c(.6, .5 , .333))
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a base R solution:

```
res <- (function(x) x/x[[1]] )(Ordercounts[,-1])
```

The part between the first parentheses is a function, allowing you to avoid writing "Ordercounts" repeatedly. You could instead use `res <- Ordercounts[,-1]/Ordercounts[,-1][[1]]`, but this is error-prone if you have a habit of using really long variable names.

This procedure also allows you to ignore the column names. Typing them may similarly be error-prone as you change the names or want to approach another data.frame in a similar way.

---

You can look at `cbind(Ordercounts[,1,drop=FALSE],res)` for your desired formatting:

```
  first_week Order.1 Order.2   Order.3
1     Week 1       1    0.86 0.6000000
2     Week 2       1    0.75 0.5000000
3     Week 3       1    0.50 0.3333333
```

Comment: This totally works for the dataset I put up here. With my working data, Ordercounts[, -1]  has class "tbl_df" and "data.frame" so it gives me an error saying "  ‘/’ only defined for equally-sized data frames " - because I'm dividing a dataframe by another one that's not the same size. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: @Sfuj Maybe `function(x) lapply(x,function(z) z/x[,1])`? Or try switching `x[,1]` to `x[[1]]`..? I'm not familiar with `tbl_df`.

Comment: Np, I've now switch to using that in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Using dplyr:

```
Ordercounts %>%  
    mutate_each(funs(./Order.1), rev(starts_with("Order")))
```

Or, a longer, but possibly 'better', solution:

```
Ordercounts %>%  
    mutate(x=Order.1) %>% 
    mutate_each(funs(./x), starts_with("Order")) %>%
    select(-x)
```

Theres probably still a better solution

```
  first_week Order.1 Order.2   Order.3
1     Week 1       1    0.86 0.6000000
2     Week 2       1    0.75 0.5000000
3     Week 3       1    0.50 0.3333333
```